# How to display a kendo template inside another?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've a kendo popup template for add/edit.
I need to display a list of product with a check-box inside a list-view in that template.I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995882/kendo-listview-with-checkbox-along-with-select-all-checkbox-option) to create a list-view of check boxes. How do i use this inside another template.

****Looking for something like this****
[image]

**Html**

```
 <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="myTemplate">

        <div class="item click" value="#=ProductID#" data-bind="checked: isSelected">
            <input type="checkbox" class="click" />
            <span class="checkbox">#:ProductName#</span>
        </div>
    </script>

    <!-- Kendo popup editor template -->
    <script id="popup_editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <div style="width:700px">

            <div style=" margin-left:100px">
                <label for="Product">Products </label>
                <div id="listView" class="k-listview" style="width:150px;height:250px;overflow-y:scroll;margin-top:10px">
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </script>
```

**script**

```
      $scope.productddlDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: "api/product"
            }
        });

    $("#listView").kendoListView({
        dataSource: $scope.productddlDataSource,
        template: kendo.template($("#myTemplate").html())
    });

    //KENDO UI POP_UP

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        dataSource: $scope.data,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        scrollable: false,
        toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "ADD Product" }],
        editable: {
            mode: "popup",
            template: kendo.template($("#popup_editor").html()),
            confirmation: true
        },
...
.
.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented by *kendo-angular-template* for the inner List-box. Please see the example here http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listview/angular.

Answer (score 2):

If you post some sample code showing what you're trying to do it would help.  In general though, a template within a template is possible and I've done this in projects before.
Here's an example directly from Telerik:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/template-inside-template
and another example:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/nested-templates